# lookup col a or b and find match - return column 3

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to compare two different sheets
Sheet one has company names
sheet two has company names in two different columns
*note the company names are not exactly the same, i.e one may have a comma or dot and the other won't*

I am trying to find the match from sheet one on sheet two and have it return a value from column 3 (sheet two)
I need it to look in column a and if no match look in column b

Unfortunately when i ask for an exact match it returns an error, but otherwise will return a completely different name than the one I want.

Any advice?

Comment: Any lookup that does not have the *exact match* parameter set requires that the lookup column be sorted. You might want to consider a *helper column* that strips out commas, periods and double spaces. Post some of the worst examples (redacted of course) and more help may be able to be offered.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for this. It will read in two tables and return the best match (or matches), along with confidence and similarity scores.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

I cant follow your second paragraph above, but I think for your scenario I would run a first pass using the first pair of columns. Then I would create a new sheet with just the unmatched rows + rows with low confidence and similarity scores. Then I would run a second Fuzzy Lookup using the second pair of columns.  The last task would be to collect all the matches together.

If this is a one-off task I would just do those steps manually.  If it needs to be repeated I would wrap it in Queries using the Power Query Add-In, to automate the splitting and collation of data.  You cant automate calling the Fuzzy Lookup Add-In (yet - I hear they are working on this), but you can automate the other steps.